# Why do we have to type the class name twice when instantiating a new object in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, instantiation

When we create a new object in Java, we use the syntax:

```
ClassName instancename = new ClassName();
```

My question is why do we have to type the class name at the beginning? Why is there simply not an 'object' keyword?

Example:

```
object instancename = new ClassName();
```

Comment: Funny, `Object instancename = new Classname();` will compile :)

Comment: So what's the benefit of using the class name over a generic Object type?

Comment: The declared class doesn't have to be the same as the instantiated class: `List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>()`. Food for thought...

Comment: Because Java is static typed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: that is part of the reason, but not all of it. Plenty of languages these day have some kind of "auto" or "value" keyword that basically says "hey, compile, you know the type, don't make me write it again". There's little reason why Java couldn't have that as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Wouldn't type erasure interfere with that?

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes, but sadly Java haven't implemented something like that, so we still have to declare the type of the variable :(

Comment: Don't you lose the ability to use the subclass's functions when you declare a variable as a class then initialize it with a subclass? (e.g. if declared as `Food sandwich = new Sandwich()` then `sandwich` will have the properties of `Food` but not `Sandwich`)

Comment: @Arc676 No, you can still cast it to the subtype if required to access some of the subtype's methods

Comment: @Arc676 If that's true, why would that happen? What's the point?

Comment: @Arc676 that's the power of the dynamic languages that static languages like Java lack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the left hand:

```
ClassName instancename
```

The `ClassName` is declaring type (= class) of variable `instancename`.

On the right hand:

```
new ClassName();
```

The `ClassName()` is invoking a (constructor) method named `ClassName()`.

So, you are doing two things at once.

```
ClassName instancename;         // declaring type
instancename = new ClassName(); // invoking method
```

Your example:

```
ClassName instancename = new ClassName();
```

is just shortened style of the two instructions.

There are other styles of getting an instance of a class -- `newInstance()` or `getInstance()` for example.

That is: declaration of type and method of instantiation are the separate things. They are needed for their own purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Object is the parent class for all java classes. When you call the class the first time,

```
ClassName instancename
```

it creates memory reference for that variable name, but that reference isn't pointing to an actual object yet since it hasn't been created in memory. When you call it the second time,

```
instancename = new ClassName();
```

it calls ClassName's default constructor which allocates memory and actually creates the object in memory.

It's safer to create an instance of ClassName instead of object when working with multiple classes. If you use object to declare your classes, you will often have to frequently use typecasting so your code will compile because the compiler will know which class to look at to find the corresponding class's method.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why do we have to type the class name at the beginning? Why is there simply not an 'object' keyword?

You are doing two "things", you are creating a reference that can hold a `ClassName`, and creating an instance of `ClassName`.

Many languages can infer one side from the other however Java (by default, see [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/val.html)) can not. From memory with was originally done this way to keep the language specification simple.

Answer (score -1):

There are many new languages out there that can intuit the types of created objects. Java is one of them.

```
new ArrayList<String> ()
```

Java knows the type of the result is `ArrayList<String>`. However, in Java, you do not have to assign the result to an object of that type, you can use any type in the hierarchy all the way up to `Object` - in fact you are even encouraged to do so. Most commonly you would move up to the nearest `interface` (`List<String>` in this case) but going further up can be useful (`Iterable<String>` would work well here). The recommended technique in this case would be:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String> ();
```

or - more succinctly in Java 7

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<> ();
```

or

```
Iterable<String> myList = new ArrayList<> ();
```

Comment: Do you mean List<String> is an interface?

Comment: Yes - [List<String>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an `interface`.

Comment: But the interface can't be instantiated

Comment: Correct - `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String> ();` note using `new ArrayList...` to instantiate a `List`.